# How to programmatically schedule sale dates in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to schedule the sale period in woocommerce when a post is saved (published).

I have tried both methods below but neither of them are working. The code is being called at the right time, just not updating the post meta.

Neither methods are updating the sale schedule.

```
add_action('save_post_product', array($this, 'knpv_new_product_from_draft'), 10, 2);
add_action('edit_post_product', array($this, 'knpv_new_product_from_draft'), 10, 2);
public function knpv_new_product_from_draft($post_id, $post){   


    //Get todays date and the date 15 days from now
    $datefrom = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
    $dateto = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+15 days',$datefrom)));

    //Method 1
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);

    if( !empty(get_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price', true)) ){         
        $product->set_date_on_sale_from( $datefrom );
        $product->set_date_on_sale_to( $dateto );
    }

    $product->save();       

    //Method 2    
    $var = update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', $datefrom);
    $var2 = update_post_meta($post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to',   $dateto);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following ways:

**1st Way** - Since WooCommerce 3:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', array($this, 'save_wc_product_meta_data') );
public function save_wc_product_meta_data($product) {   

    if( isset( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) && $_POST['_sale_price'] >= 0 ){
        $product->set_date_on_sale_from( strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));
        $product->set_date_on_sale_to( strtotime( date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+15 days'))));
    }
}
```

---

**2nd Way** - the old way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', array($this, 'save_wc_product_meta_data') );
public function save_wc_product_meta_data($product_id) {   

    if( get_post_meta($product_id, '_sale_price', true) >= 0 ){
        update_post_meta($product_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));
        update_post_meta($product_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', strtotime( date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+15 days'))));
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Both ways work.

---

> **Addition:**
>
> To make that happen **only when the post status is set on "publish"**, you can add the following to the **`IF`** statement existing conditions:

```
&& isset($_POST['post_status']) && $_POST['post_status'] === 'publish'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, if I could ask you to expand though. As per OP, I'm looking to implement this only when a product goes from Draft to Publish.

Comment: @AlexKnopp This is a different question / answer for a product going from Draft to publish status, as this will not be handled by all that hooks... Please accept this answer as it works for your initial provided question and it will be useful to others. Then ask a similar new question asking specifically for transition status from draft to publish. Thank you. I will answer your new question if nobody do it before me. You can notify me here with the new question link.

Comment: The original question does include the fact that Im trying to do this on post save. 
"Im trying to schedule the sale period in woocommerce when a post is saved (published)."

Comment: @AlexKnopp I have updated my answer with an addition that will allow to restrict the code to "publish" post status only.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I have manged to sort it though and will post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this wasn't working was because the meta was being updated after the save_post action had finished. So I was updating the meta, then the empty values from the form were also updating them and clearing them.

So I did it like this.

```
add_action('save_post_product', array($this, 'knpv_new_product_from_draft'), 10, 2);
add_action('edit_post_product', array($this, 'knpv_new_product_from_draft'), 10, 2);
public function knpv_new_product_from_draft($post_id, $post){  
  //If the post is being published. 
  if (get_post_status($post_id) == 'publish') {

    //Set the values from the posted form data.
    $_POST['_sale_price_dates_from'] = date('Y-m-d');
    $_POST['_sale_price_dates_to'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($datefrom.' +15 days'));

  }
}
```